# crawling using R

Tags: r, html-table, web-crawler

all.

I need some help from the experts.

I tried to get apartment name, number of rooms and price in Korea.

[This is the page](http://land.findall.co.kr/land_new/subLand.asp?hidSectionCd=6&tmphidSearchGbn=area&selTradeKind=0&hidCategoryCode=0&hidtxtSearch=&txtWolamountMin=0&txtWolamountMax=0&txtPyengMin=0&txtPyengMax=0&txtPremiumMin=0&txtPremiumMax=0&hidListGbn=0&hidOrd=&hidOptCode=0&hidMainSubGbn=S&hidDataLoadGbn=L&hidOptStr=&hidMetro=%BC%AD%BF%EF&hidCity=%B0%AD%B3%B2%B1%B8&hidDong=&hidMapX=0&hidMapY=0&page=1&totalcount=2132&hidContractId=&LineAdNo=&strMP=&BestInfoCnt=&reCommonCnt=&BestInfo_Goods=&isFirst=0&hidSearchGbn=area&selMetro=%BC%AD%BF%EF&selCity=%B0%AD%B3%B2%B1%B8&selDong=&txtSearch=&selRadius=00&selPriceMin=10&selPriceMax=000&selRoomCnt=000&selBathRoom=000&Premium=0-0&wolamount=0-0&Pyeng=&intMilli=&intPyeng=).

my code is:

```
url <- "http://land.findall.co.kr/land_new/subLand.asp?hidSectionCd=6&tmphidSearchGbn=area&selTradeKind=0&hidCategoryCode=0&hidtxtSearch=&txtWolamountMin=0&txtWolamountMax=0&txtPyengMin=0&txtPyengMax=0&txtPremiumMin=0&txtPremiumMax=0&hidListGbn=0&hidOrd=&hidOptCode=0&hidMainSubGbn=S&hidDataLoadGbn=L&hidOptStr=&hidMetro=%BC%AD%BF%EF&hidCity=%B0%AD%B3%B2%B1%B8&hidDong=&hidMapX=0&hidMapY=0&page=1&totalcount=2132&hidContractId=&LineAdNo=&strMP=&BestInfoCnt=0&reCommonCnt=0&BestInfo_Goods=0&isFirst=0&hidSearchGbn=area&selMetro=%BC%AD%BF%EF&selCity=%B0%AD%B3%B2%B1%B8&selDong=&txtSearch=&selRadius=00&selPriceMin=10&selPriceMax=000&selRoomCnt=000&selBathRoom=000&Premium=0-0&wolamount=0-0&Pyeng=&intMilli=&intPyeng="
homes <- read_html(url)
titles <- carInfos %>% html_nodes('.elip') %>% html_text()
```

and I could get the names of apartments.

Number of rooms are under s but, I cannot go further from this problem.
I attached a part that is hard for me to get through.

[image]

Comment: Please use plain text for code and data, not images, so users can copy/paste easily.

Comment: Have you tried using [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/)? Its a chrome extension that handles css selector generation.

Comment: The site allows scraping of this path but we don't really know what you want to scrape. There are at least 4 XHR requests that this site makes. We need more information to help you.'

Answer (score 0):

This probably could use some cleanup, but I think the basics are there. Per the comments, [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) is going to be your friend:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://land.findall.co.kr/land_new/subLand.asp?hidSectionCd=6&tmphidSearchGbn=area&selTradeKind=0&hidCategoryCode=0&hidtxtSearch=&txtWolamountMin=0&txtWolamountMax=0&txtPyengMin=0&txtPyengMax=0&txtPremiumMin=0&txtPremiumMax=0&hidListGbn=0&hidOrd=&hidOptCode=0&hidMainSubGbn=S&hidDataLoadGbn=L&hidOptStr=&hidMetro=%BC%AD%BF%EF&hidCity=%B0%AD%B3%B2%B1%B8&hidDong=&hidMapX=0&hidMapY=0&page=1&totalcount=2132&hidContractId=&LineAdNo=&strMP=&BestInfoCnt=0&reCommonCnt=0&BestInfo_Goods=0&isFirst=0&hidSearchGbn=area&selMetro=%BC%AD%BF%EF&selCity=%B0%AD%B3%B2%B1%B8&selDong=&txtSearch=&selRadius=00&selPriceMin=10&selPriceMax=000&selRoomCnt=000&selBathRoom=000&Premium=0-0&wolamount=0-0&Pyeng=&intMilli=&intPyeng="
homes <- read_html(url)

apt_name <- homes %>%
  html_nodes(".address .elip") %>%
  html_text()

num_rooms <- homes %>%
  html_nodes("#spCommonList td:nth-child(5)") %>%
  html_text()

price <- homes %>%
  html_nodes(".line .price") %>%
  html_text()

results <- bind_cols(apt_name = apt_name, num_rooms = num_rooms, price = price)
results

# A tibble: 30 x 3
#         apt_name num_rooms          price
#            <chr>     <chr>          <chr>
#  1   개포우성1차         4    전세120,000
#  2 개포주공1단지         3    매매166,000
#  3          삼성         3    매매100,000
#  4       한양1차         3    매매170,000
#  5       한양6차         3    매매188,000
#  6       현대8차         3    매매184,000
#  7       한양1차         3    매매150,000
#  8          동현         3     전세52,000
#  9       한양6차         3     전세55,000
# 10 우정에쉐르III         3 월세10,000/185
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Oh, my god. Thank you so much!!

Comment: can I ask one more? Instead of getting individual information, can I get the entire table?